# Custom pipeline task - wait for an external process to complete?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm working on a custom task for a build pipeline. This task starts a long-running (days) external process. After starting the process, I want to pause the pipeline execution and resume it only when the process is finished.

The ideal flow would be:

1. Start the task
2. Start the external process
3. Pause the pipeline execution (free up the agent)
4. External process takes days....
5. Process completed
6. On completion of the process, calls Azure DevOps API to resume my pipeline

I would say it is somehow similar to a Manual Validation task but with a webhook instead of user input.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just have separate pipelines for phase 1 (completes when successfully starting external process) and a phase 2 (the process starts this build pipeline using the API).

The question here is what inputs/outputs you depend on.

The manual validation task which exists for yaml is only supported on agentless jobs probably for the same reason (you don't want to keep an agent busy when it's just waiting).